# Sound with JOGL?

Tags: java, audio, graphics, jogl

I have a JOGL app, and I'd like to programmatically play audio files. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

JOGL (and OpenGL in general) is not an audio library. Perhaps you want [JOAL](http://jogamp.org/joal/www/)?

Answer (score 1):

JOAL is [here](http://jogamp.org/joal/www/), no more on java.net.

Answer (score 0):

JOGL is for 2D and 3D graphics renderer, but does not include audio stream.
If you want to deal with audio, JOAL come in handy!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).